# f:ajax fires only once in IE

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Here is code

```
 <h:outputLink styleClass="button" value="javascript:void(0);">
              Text
                <f:ajax execute="@form" event="click"  listener="#{commentView.saveComment}" render="main_form" />
                </h:outputLink>
```

My commentView bean is @ViewScoped.

Works in Chrome as i expected but in IE only once.

Thanks for any idea.

EDIT:

it behaves like it is ok by changing `render="main_form"` to `render=":main_form"`

**but the problem continues in eclipse's browser.**

Comment: That's a solution to a different problem than the one you described (it would have failed as hard in Chrome as in IE). So perhaps you just interpreted the problem wrong.

Comment: Whats the purpose of this? value="javascript:void(0);"

Comment: not to refresh the page, not to allow scroll go up, thanks for attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason may be stopping script in the middle because of error. Use Developer Tools (F12 key in IE), there is script debugger that can help with bug tracking.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, in my case it worked fine in all browsers except that in IE9 the ajax was fired only once .

I was using `render="@form"` and when I changed it to `render="@all"`, it worked fine. I dunno why, since I only have one Form in that page, and all my components are in that form, anyway, I hope this is useful.